# INNER JOIN 1 campo primario a varios campos foraneos en una misma tabla

Tags: sql, mysqli

solicito su ayuda para mejorar una consulta SQL.

Hay ocaciones en las que tengo una tabla quiero relacionar varios campos foraneos a un campo primario de otra tabla, pero el problema es que hay mas de 1 campo con llave foranea.

Algo asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente lo que ago es hacer el inner join 2 veces a la misma tabla:

```
SELECT 
    E.nombre AS Nombre, 
    U1.nombre AS `Integrante 1`,
    U2.nombre AS `Integrante 2` 
FROM equipo AS E 
INNER JOIN usuario AS U1 ON E.usuario1_id = U1.id 
INNER JOIN usuario AS U2 ON E.usuario2_id = U2.id
```

Quedando graficamente algo asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo:

> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f54a3/1/0

La pregunta es si se puede obtener el mismo resultado de una forma mas optima sin tener que hacer el inner join 'n' veces a la misma tabla.

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Creo que no se puede porque necesitas devolver los resultados en columnas diferentes, a la hora de hacer el `inner join` no podrás diferenciar quien es `Integrante 1` y quien es `Integrante 2` porque estarán referenciadas al mismo identificador de tabla `U1` al acceder a `U1.nombre` te devolverá los 2 resultados tanto  `Integrante 1` como `Integrante 2`

Comment: Si quieres usar un `inner join` nada más, pienso que sería [algo así](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f54a3/8) del resto no veo otra manera de hacerlo.

Comment: @VictorPerdomo el query esta bien, va a traer un registros distinto en cada join

Comment: Es que sé que el problema no es el `inner join` sino que desea mostrar los datos en columnas diferentes, eso no lo va a poder hacer a menos que haga referencia a identificadores de tablas diferentes.

Comment: si se puede hacer, tienen identificadores diferentes.. igual este query se puede resolver perfectamente sin joins.

Comment: Si pero lee el problema el no quiere tener que usar `inner join` 'n' veces.

Comment: Ahi puse una respuesta sin ningun join

Comment: Listo, ya lo vi pero no se si es lo más optimo son 3 `SELECT` pensé que había una manera de hacerlo en una sola consulta.

Comment: Los joins son selects tambien... fijate en un explain plan que hacen ;)

Comment: Pero entonces, lo que haces es emular 2 `inner join` no tiene mucho sentido es lo mismo que hacer lo que él hace pero de otra manera.

Comment: Ok el problema viene cuando se juntan los dos campos con llave foranea pero del resultado del inner join, imagina que tienes 2 tablas cada una tiene el id del usuario que creo el registro, haces el join y quieres devolver el nombre del usuario en ves del id, sería algo igual se tendía que hacer 2 join para resolver cada id de usuario.

Comment: Claro lógicamente debes crear 2 `joins` son 2 tablas diferentes.

Comment: @VictorPerdomo siempre hay que revisar el explain plan. puede que el select sea diferente porque termine entrando por algun indice.

Answer (score 4):

Buenas tardes Jose El Junior, Creo que tus relaciones no están normalizadas, deberían ser algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así tu inner join quedaría de esta forma:

```
SELECT 
    USU.nombre AS USUARIO,
    EQ.nombre AS EQUIPO
FROM USUARIO AS USU
INNER JOIN EQUIPO_USUARIO AS EUS ON USU.id = EUS.id_usuario
INNER JOIN EQUIPO AS EQ ON EUS.id_equipo = EQ.id
```

Comment: Sus relaciones estan correctas. se puede hacer de las dos maneras, aunque la que usa el es mas comun.

Comment: de verdad? Que pasa si el equipo tiene 3 usuarios más ? se debe de agregar una columna para cada usuario ?

Comment: En tal caso lo que estaría mal sería el diseño de sus tablas más no el query.

Comment: Todo depende de las reglas de negocios. Yo he visto tablas asi hasta con 5 relaciones a una sola tabla.

Comment: Correcto, pero en este caso creo que eso no sería lo ideal, o que piensas ?

Comment: Todo depende de las reglas de negocios. No es no ideal o ideal, es como convenga a la base de datos. una tabla intermedia por ahi complejiza todo, porque en este caso son todos usuarios, pero que pasa si cada uno tiene un rol diferente.. ademas la tabla intermedia deberia especificar el rol y los queries serian todavia mucho mas complejos de ejecutar

Comment: Creo que agregar una tabla intermedia para realizar la relación de muchos a muchos es la mejor opción y no tendrias que estar agregando un nuevo join por cada usuario que ingreses al sistema., de esta forma optimizas el query. saludos Cesar.

Answer (score 1):

Tu query se puede resolver perfectamente sin usar un solo join.

Para ello, vamos a hacer una subquery en cada columna que queres agregar

```
SELECT 
    E.nombre AS Nombre, 
    (select nombre from usuario where usuario1_id = id ) as `Integrante 1`,
    (select nombre from usuario where usuario2_id = id ) as `Integrante 2`
FROM equipo AS E
```

Comment: tengo una duda, al ejecutar esta consulta, que tanto afectaría en el plan de ejecución ?

Comment: Hay que revisarlo en los dos casos. puede que sea exactamente el mismo. depende de las tablas y los indices